# Connecting to Amazon ActiveMQ with username & password

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, activemq-classic, broker

I'm trying to connect to ActiveMQ Amazon broker via SSL. My application is written in `C#`.
Previously, I connected via TCP to localhost ActiveMQ broker, which worked:

```
using Apache.NMS;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Commands;


void Connect()
{       
    String brokerUri = "activemq:tcp://" + host + ":" + port + "? transport.useLogging=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&userName=myUsername&password=myPassword";
    NMSConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
    IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    connection.Start();
}
```

To connect to ActiveMQ Amazon broker via SSL, I have modified the code in the following way:

```
void Connect()
{
    String brokerUri = "ssl://" + host + ":" + port + "? transport.useLogging=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&userName=myUsername&password=myPassword";
    SslTransportFactory transportFactory = new SslTransportFactory();
    Uri uri = new Uri(brokerUri);
    ITransport transport = transportFactory.CreateTransport(uri);
    transport.Command = Command;
    transport.Exception = Exception;
    transport.Start();

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
    IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

    Connection con = (Connection)connection;
    con.ITransport = transport;

    con.Start();                  => Here the exception is thrown: User name [null] or password is invalid. 
}

private void Exception(ITransport sender, Exception command)
{            
}

private void Command(ITransport sender, Command command)
{            
}
```

However, upon starting the connection, `User name [null] or password is invalid.` Exception is thrown.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently passing user credentials via the URI. However, I don't see any reference to `username` or `password` in the [URI reference documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/activemq-uri-configuration.html). Also, the fact that the exception indicates the user name is `null` indicates the user credentials in your URI are simply being ignored.

Instead you should pass the user credentials in the `CreateConnection` method as documented [here](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/M_Apache_NMS_IConnectionFactory_CreateConnection_2_52fce4af.htm), e.g.:

```
IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection("myUsername", "myPassword");
```